What is missing in for loop in XSLT?
I tried writing XSLT from below given XML but not getting right output.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n0:EPCISDocument xmlns:n0="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" schemaVersion="1.2" creationDate="2024-03-12T14:28:47.272374Z">
   <EPCISBody>
      <EventList>
         <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</parentID>
            <childEPCs>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.354159881283</epc>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.438941790942</epc>
            </childEPCs>
         </AggregationEvent>
         <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</parentID>
            <childEPCs>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.497811017409</epc>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.600301574096</epc>
            </childEPCs>
         </AggregationEvent>
         <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</parentID>
            <childEPCs>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</epc>
               <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</epc>
            </childEPCs>
         </AggregationEvent>
      </EventList>
   </EPCISBody>
</n0:EPCISDocument>

Actual output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:despatchAdvice xmlns:tns="urn:ean.ucc:deliver:2">
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>
            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>           <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
</tns:despatchAdvice>

Expected output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:despatchAdvice xmlns:ns3="urn:ean.ucc:deliver:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>
            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>
            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <parentLevelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</levelIdentification>
      </parentLevelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.354159881283</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.438941790942</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>
            <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <parentLevelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</levelIdentification>
      </parentLevelId>
      <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.497811017409</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
         <listForEachItem>
            <serialNumber>urn:epc:id:sgtin:539150714.0666.600301574096</serialNumber>
         </listForEachItem>
      </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
</ns3:despatchAdvice>

Below is the XSLT code I tried but not giving expected output.
<xsl:template match="/">
      <tns:despatchAdvice>
         <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent">
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent[contains(childEPCs/epc, 'sscc')]/childEPCs/epc">
               <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
                  <logisticUnitIdentification>
                     <serialShipmentContainerCode>
                        <serialShippingContainerCode>
                           <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent/parentID"/>
                        </serialShippingContainerCode>
                     </serialShipmentContainerCode>
                  </logisticUnitIdentification>
                  <levelId>
                     <levelIdentification>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent/parentID"/>
                     </levelIdentification>
                  </levelId>
                  <despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
                     <listForEachItem>
                        <serialNumber>
                           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </serialNumber>
                     </listForEachItem>
                  </despatchAdviceItemContainmentLineItem>
               </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tns:despatchAdvice>
   </xsl:template>

What is missing here in XSLT code I have written? How to achieve right output from XSLT? Here is the scenario:
In the input file we have three AggregationEvent, loop should follow three times.
In the last AggregationEvent of the input file, we have two child epc. In the first loop, the value of parentID should appear for serialShippingContainerCode and levelIdentification. In second loop, the value of parentID should appear for levelIdentification under parentLevelId and parentID of first AggregationEvent should appear for serialShippingContainerCode under serialShipmentContainerCode. In second loop only childEPCs/epc of first AggregationEvent should populate its value for serialNumber. In third loop, the value of parentID should appear for levelIdentification under parentLevelId and parentID of first AggregationEvent should appear for serialShippingContainerCode under serialShipmentContainerCode. In third loop only childEPCs/epc of second AggregationEvent should populate its value for serialNumber.

Please explain the required logic in words. Reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem and using easy to recognize values would also help - see: [mcve].

One thing that immediately stands out in your attempt is that you start your inner iteration from the root element, instead of from the context established by the outer one (not sure why you need this structure at all). And the same applies to the 2 xsl:value-of instructions.

@michael, I have updated the question with scenario. Please check if that helps.

Sorry, I am not able to follow your explanation. You're telling us what the result should be, but not why.

@michael, question is why only. I am not getting right output from the XSLT code I have written. I have mentioned the actual and expected output. Could you please check once and suggest. Please let me know if am missing anything so that I can update the question for more clarification.

No, I can't tell you why you're not getting the expected result when I don't  understand what is it that you trying to do.

An xsl:for-each instruction changes the context. Within the for-each, you should be using relative paths, not absolute paths.
You write
for each /a/b
  for each /a/b/c
    value of /a/b/c/d

which should be
for each /a/b
  for each c
    value of d  

